# Opposite of MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping?

Tags: c#, mime-types, mime

There exists `MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(string filename)`

Does there exist a .Net function, that does the 'opposite'.  That takes a mime string and returns the file type extension ?

Answer (score 3):

You can read the registry to get that information.

```
var mapping = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.GetSubKeyNames()
               .Select(key => new
                {
                    Key = key,
                    ContentType = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(key).GetValue("Content Type")
                })
                .Where(x => x.ContentType != null)
                .ToLookup(x => x.ContentType, x => x.Key);

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(";",mapping["image/jpeg"]));
```

Comment: When I use this for "image/jpeg" on my system, it returns .jfif, .jpeg and .jpg.  Any idea how the could could distinguish that .jpg would be my preferred extension?  I've looked in the registry and haven't found anything that I could use...

Answer (score 0):

Having just run into this myself and being unhappy with having a mismatch between `GetMimeMapping` and its reverse (via providing an alternate list to what `MimeMapping` uses), I dug into `MimeMapping` itself to get its internal mappings.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetExtensions(this string mimeType)
{
    var mappingDictionaryField = typeof(MimeMapping).GetField("_mappingDictionary", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

    if (mappingDictionaryField == null)
        return new string[0];

    // get the internal dictionary used for mime type lookup
    var mappingDictionary = mappingDictionaryField.GetValue(null); 

    if (mappingDictionary == null)
        return new string[0];

    // get type that owns the populate method and populated dictionary
    var dictionaryType = mappingDictionary.GetType().BaseType;

    if (dictionaryType == null)
        return new string[0];

    var populateMethod = dictionaryType.GetMethod("PopulateMappings", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    if (populateMethod == null)
        return new string[0];

    populateMethod.Invoke(mappingDictionary, null); 

    // get the populated mapping dictionary
    var mappingField = dictionaryType.GetField("_mappings", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    if (mappingField == null)
        return new string[0];

    var mapping = mappingField.GetValue(mappingDictionary) as IDictionary<string, string>;

    if (mapping == null)
        return new string[0];

    var extensions = mapping.Where(x => x.Value == mimeType)
                            .Select(x => x.Key);

    return extensions;
}
```

I decided not to throw exceptions in the case of reflection failures, and just return no extensions, because it matched my personal use case.